# SNI windows xp workaround

Tags: windows, windows-xp, sni

Is there some workaround so I can get SNI working for IE on windows xp ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no official (Microsoft-Supported) way of making this work.
I wouldn't advise investing your time and effort in any hacks that purport to make it work (assuming you can find any -- a quick search didn't turn up anything promising).   You would just be setting yourself up for trouble later...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try instead to use a certificate with subjectAltName fields.